# Unhandled event loop exception GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, eclipse, garbage-collection

I am getting Unhandled event loop exception GC overhead limit exceeded error in eclipse ,with this error eclipse hangs on.

I searched for resolution and applied tricks but didn't work.

In eclipse.ini file I added below to increase memory allocation for eclipse, but no luck.

-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I get "An internal error occurred during: "Decoration Calculation".
Java heap space" error too sometime.

Comment: Probably a misbehaving plug-in.

Comment: Each of those entries in the eclipse.ini must be on a separate line (and below the -vmargs entry).

Comment: may be you can increase the size to 1024m. i got that error during my eclipse plugin execution,i changed it in runAs-> run configurations. Considering your scenario you can put -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m next to the (-vmargs) inside the eclipse.ini file.

Comment: and try to start it as eclipse -clean from command line

Answer (score 0):

Oracle [mentioned](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#par_gc.oom) that

> If more than 98% of the total time is spent in garbage collection and
>   less than 2% of the heap is recovered, an OutOfMemoryError will be
>   thrown.This feature is designed to prevent applications from running
>   for an extended period of time while making little or no progress
>   because the heap is too small. If necessary, this feature can be
>   disabled by adding the option -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit to the command
>   line.

Basically Eclipse would need more memory if you are using more number of plugins to your IDE environment like C++ , PHP, Java EE etc... The Xmx will provide additional memory for java to run. If you are using more plugins in your IDE, try using a basic one which contains only the essential core functions.